# Dynamic Data Model with Dynamic Fields and properties

Tags: c#

Good day, I want to ask how to create a dynamic class with dynamic fields in C# that will be passed in class as string and create a dynamic properties as well.
And return a class to serves as data model. Thank you

Create a dynamic data model that accept a string parameter that will served as fields and return a class or data model.

Comment: What's the intention of having such a dynamic behavior? Can you share an example of  expected behavior?

Comment: The intention is that the user will decide or provide the fields he needs or want to .
So we need to create a model that serves as container/holder of the data we return from query.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.